# Trying to create a service but it won't start

Tags: ubuntu, services, init-script

Apologies if this is an obvious answer, I am a Windows admin professionally and only use Linux in my homelab to try to learn new things - so I'm very inexperienced with Linux.

I am working on writing a Puppet module to install/configure Sonarr, and am running into trouble with getting Sonarr set up as a service (testing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). The install and creation of the script are going fine, but I am running into problems getting the service to actually *start*. Here is the init.d script I have, courtesy of shameless stealing from the internet:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nzbdrone
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example
# Description:       Example start-stop-daemon - Debian
### END INIT INFO

NAME="nzbdrone"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
APPDIR="/opt/NzbDrone"
APPBIN="/usr/bin/mono"
APPARGS="/opt/NzbDrone/NzbDrone.exe"
USER="nzbdrone"
GROUP="nzbdrone"

# Include functions 
set -e
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

start() {
  printf "Starting '$NAME'... "
  start-stop-daemon --start --chuid "$USER:$GROUP" --background --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid --chdir "$APPDIR" --exec "$APPBIN" -- $APPARGS || true
  printf "done\n"
}

#We need this function to ensure the whole process tree will be killed
killtree() {
    local _pid=$1
    local _sig=${2-TERM}
    for _child in $(ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${_pid}); do
        killtree ${_child} ${_sig}
    done
    kill -${_sig} ${_pid}
}

stop() {
  printf "Stopping '$NAME'... "
  [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || \
  while test -d /proc/$(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid); do
    killtree $(cat /var/run/$NAME.pid) 15
    sleep 0.5
  done 
  [ -z `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid 2>/dev/null` ] || rm /var/run/$NAME.pid
  printf "done\n"
}

status() {
  status_of_proc -p /var/run/$NAME.pid "" $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The problem is, this won't start. Or more precisely, it starts but syslog shows that the process is crashing, then being restarted, over and over. The thing that puzzles me is that if I run `/etc/init.d/nzbdrone start`, the process starts great. It is *only* when I run `service nzbdrone start` that it starts the crashing over and over. My google-fu turned up [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120405/can-start-service-with-init-d-script-however-doing-service-service-name-start) similar question, but the answer there made mention of environment variables and I can't spot anything in this script that isn't being initialized by the script. Can anyone help me spot what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up finding the issue, or possibly issues. I first noticed that in my Puppet code that was creating the user to run the service, the variable for the user's home dir was misspelled (which caused the user's home dir to be set to "/home/" in /etc/passwd). Second, I realized that Puppet does not automatically create the home dir unless you tell it to, so I went ahead and had Puppet manage the user's home dir. Finally, I set the user's shell to /bin/bash after finding another Stack Exchange answer which mentioned that they had a similar issue when their service user's shell was set to /bin/false.

When I corrected all of these issues, the service starts great. I'm not sure if it was only one of these or a combination of multiple, but hopefully this will help someone else if they run into similar issues in the future.